# Fuzzy search box widget with `Shiny` in R?

Tags: r, elasticsearch, shiny, fuzzy-search

Has anyone created or seen a Shiny app featuring **search box widget giving contextual suggestions as you type, based on *fuzzy* matching**?

Bloomberg terminal uses it, Google uses it. One of the possible underlying technologies is called [`elasticsearch.org` 's fuzzy query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html), with two R implementations:

1. `duncantl/RElasticSearch`
2. `ropensci/elastic`

Search box filter coming with the basic `Shiny`'s [datatable](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/basic-datatable.html) doesn't quite cut it.

If this is something yet to be integrated with Shiny, any rough guide how to build it? I suspect it would be extremely useful on biggish tables (or documents) with lots of text, when you want to look for specific rows, without displaying the full table.

Comment: Are you looking to use this search box widget for a data table?

Comment: Not necessarily. Shiny`s `datatable`'s search box was just an illustration of what currently exists and remotely resembles what I described

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a combobox could be fed a list from [stringdist()](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/index.html) that would compare the input string against a known list and provide the items with the 10 items with the shortest string distance. Would probably be very inefficient with huge lists, but the algorithm is fairly fast when comparing against a short list.

One of the stringdist methods even compares based on how words are pronounced, not sure if that's useful.

Comment: This is definitely easier than setting up an elasticsearch server, feeding it data, and writing an observe() function. Could also use `agrep` instead of `stringdist`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using selectInput(), then you can set the parameter "choices" to a vector, and the contents of that vector will appear as the user types. The problem with this is that the user cannot select anything that is not contained in the vector.

UI:

```
selectInput(
    "reference_name", label = h3("Selection"), choices = vector_of_search_possibilities, selectize = TRUE, selected = "Alabama"
  )
```

SERVER:
reference this object using

```
input$reference_name
```

Comment: thanks. will `vector_of_search_possibilities` update suggestions as-you-type (same experience as google.com searchbox)?

Comment: yes it will! items that contain the partial string that has already been typed will appear below like suggestions in google